# SOQL in property get method

Tags: apex

I have a static property:

```
public static Map<String,Opportunity> CEOpportunities{
    get{
            CEOpportunities = new Map<String,Opportunity>();
            For(Opportunity o : [select Id,Name,OwnerId from Opportunity where CE_Record_Opp__c=true and NAME like '%2015'])
            {
                CEOpportunities.put(o.OwnerId, o);
            } 

        return CEOpportunities;
    }
}
```

I'm accessing this Map from another class where I insert new opportunity records so the query result changes.

My question is: when does this soql query executed? Is it executed everytime I access the property? Or just the first time I access the property?

If it's only the first time I access the property, how can I get the updated query result?

**UPDATE**:

I'm sorry but I think I wanted to ask this case. Are the queries below executed every time I access the property? I'm not sure the property below is different from the property above. But the properties below contain only SOQL query

```
public static List<Account> TopAccounts{
    get{
          return [select Id,Name from Account limit 100];
    }
}
```

OR

```
public static Integer TopAccounts{
    get{
          return [select Count() from Account Where lastmodifieddate=TODAY];
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you don't just use a `getCEOpportunities()` method instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT** Just saw your last question - I think that if you want it to requery, you need to define a `setter` on your opportunities map and set it to null. This will force the opportunities to be requeried. Otherwise, you won't get that query run again until you get a new context (essentially until you refresh your page if you are using a VF page)

I was interested to see if this would be optimised by the VisualForce compiler and based on my simple test, I think it is.

If you have a static method called multiple times on a VF page, it looks like it's only called once by the page. Here is what I did:

Get method:

```
public static Map<Id,Account> accounts{
    get{
        if(accounts==null){
            accounts = new Map<Id,Account>([Select Id,Name From Account Limit 10]); 
            System.debug('Querying Accounts');
        }
        System.debug('Returning Accounts');
        return accounts;
    }
}
```

Three output texts referencing the static controller variable:

```
<apex:outputText>{!accounts}</apex:outputText>
<apex:outputText>{!accounts}</apex:outputText>
<apex:outputText>{!accounts}</apex:outputText>
```

Only one pair of debug statments:

```
USER_DEBUG|[9]|DEBUG|Querying Accounts
USER_DEBUG|[11]|DEBUG|Returning Accounts
```

Comment: It's called [Lazy Loading](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading).

Comment: What I was trying to determine was if the `get` method was called by each `outputText`. Turns out it's only called once (which makes sense). I've been writing code professionally for 14 years, I know what Lazy Loading is.

Comment: I'm not trying to insult you. I just found it surprising you didn't mention it considering OP *didn't even use the pattern*. I feel it adds to the conversation, but not enough to post a separate answer. It' not the sort of thing I would just edit into someone's post either...

Comment: Haha - I didn't mention it because I'm sure OP was using it, but looking up at his code, it's not there. I must have added it to my answer assuming it was in the question. Hmm, I think I'm going senile.

Comment: Haha giving them more credit than deserved! Your response makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the OP's code, the SOQL is run each time the property is accessed.

As an example, if we run this in the console we use 4 SOQL queries and the second system.debug() reflects the change we made to the AccountNumber field.

```
public static Map<String,Account> mapAccounts {
    get {
        mapAccounts = new Map<String,Account>();
        for(Account objAccount : [SELECT Id, Name, AccountNumber FROM Account WHERE Name = 'test account'])
        {
            mapAccounts.put(objAccount.Name, objAccount);
        }
        return mapAccounts;
    }   
} 


List<Account> lstAccounts1 = [SELECT Id,AccountNumber FROM Account WHERE Name = 'test account'];
for(Account objAccount : lstAccounts1)
{
    objAccount.AccountNumber = '123';
}
update lstAccounts1;

system.debug('mapAccounts before: '+mapAccounts);

List<Account> lstAccounts2 = [SELECT Id,AccountNumber FROM Account WHERE Name = 'test account'];
for(Account objAccount : lstAccounts2)
{
    objAccount.AccountNumber = '999';
}
update lstAccounts2;

system.debug('mapAccounts after: '+mapAccounts);
```

[image]
[image]

Looping over the system.debug 100+ times will exceed the SOQL governor limits.

To avoid this behavior, use the lazy loading pattern that CaspNZ shared.